# Using Countifs to count Value by Month

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-word

I am trying to count the number of issues that we have per month, e.g., how many products are off condition in January, February, etc.  These two are in a different sheet (sheet 1 = data, sheet 2 - trending). I used =COUNTIF(Data!F:F, "*Off Condition*") but this doesn't include month and only gives total issues for whole timeline.

Now I need the excel to automatically generate data or number of how many issues I have when I start to fill the form and add the issues. For 1 issue that we face, I'll fill all column in one row in Sheet 1, so Sheet 2 should be automatically filled with data from Column A and Column F.

Please help.  Thank You so much in advance.

[image]

I used =COUNTIF(Data!F:F, "*Off Condition*") but this doesn't include month and only gives total issues for whole timeline.

Comment: You need to use COUNTIFS and explain which column of the `Data` tab contains the month info. Also, are the months text or date value (in both tabs?) Is the other tab dates or months?

Answer (score 0):

The **COUNIFS** function supports multiple parameters.

```
=COUNTIFS(Data!F:F,"Off Condition",Data!G:G,"January")
```